# My index in my code doesn't work

Tags: python

```
#TASK ONE
#       LISTS      #
import sys
import time
cows = []
val = []
num4 = 0
literd = []
test1 = []
val1 = []
day = []
end = []
num2 = []
days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
daya = ["1234567"]
# COW ID VALIDATION #
h = int(input("How many cows do you have? "))
for x in range(h):
    Id = int(input("Enter the 3 digit code of your cows: "))
    if len(str(Id)) != 3:
        print("Sorry, the code ID can only be 3 digit numbers!")
        sys.exit()
    elif Id in cows:
        print("The cow ID is already in!")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        cows.append(Id)
###################
# NUMBER OF COW LITERS #
print(" ")
dayz = list(days)
cowz = list(cows)
print(" ")
print("In reality a cow can get milked 25 liters a day, beware!")
for day in days:
    print("Day: ", dayz[0])
    cowz = list(cows)
    dayz.pop(0)
    for cow in cows:
        print("Cow: ", cow)
        test1.append(float(input("How many liters did you milk the cow at AM? ")))
        test1.append(float(input("How many liters did you milk the cow at PM? ")))
val = list(test1)
########################
#ROUNDING NUMBERS AND ADDING THE LITTERS OF COW MILKED#
val = [ round(elem, 1) for elem in test1 ]
kek = list()
total = sum(map(len, daya)) * h
for x in range(total):
    num1 = val[0] + val[1]
    num2.append(num1)
    kek.append(num1)
    for x in range(2):
        val.pop(0)
num3 = list(num2)
########################################################
#               PRINTS OUT THE RESULTS                #
print(" ")
print("A table will print out in just a second showing the results.")
cowz = list(cows)
print(" ")
for day in days:
    print("Day: ", day)
    for cow in cows:
        print("Cow: ", cow, end = " ")
        print("liters: ", num2[0])
        num2.pop(0)
########################################################
cow1 = list()
#TASK TWO
# PRINTING OUT THE TOTAL LITERS OF MILK THIS WEEK#
weekly = list()
num5 = len(num3)
for x in range(num5):
    num4 += num3[0]
    num3.pop(0)
print("Total liters of milk this week", num4)
#################################################
# ADDING ALL THE LITERS FOR EACH COW #
for day in days:
    cowz = list(cows)
    for cow in cows:
        cow1.append(cowz[0])
        cow1.append(kek[0])
        cowz.pop(0)
        kek.pop(0)
##################################################
cow2 = list(cow1)
cow3 = list(cows)
cow_val = []
cow_val1 = []
print(cows, cow3)
for x in range(h):
    current = cow3[0]
    while current in cow3:
       cow_val.append(cow1[cow1.index(current)])
       cow1.pop(cow1.index(current))
       cow1.pop(cow1.index(current)+1)
    cow_val1.append(sum(cow_val))
    cow3.pop(0)
```

My friend and I tried to figure out what the problem is. We couldn't find any other possible solution and I really need this help. Here is the error that it prints out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Datboi/Documents/test.py", line 98, in <module>
    cow1.pop(cow1.index(current)+1)
ValueError: 123 is not in list
```

My problem is the last few lines. I'm not sure how to solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated :D.

If you attempt to run the code and happen to find some errors or any other improvements please do suggest things. I want to try and make my code a little bit shorter so yea.

#

Update edit.

```
for x in range(h):
    xo = cow3[0]
    while xo in cow3:
        i += 1
        if x == xo:
            sum1 = sum1 + cow1[i]
    cow_val1.append(sum1)
    cow3.pop(0)
```

This one doesn't work either for some reason it doesn't allow anything to happen. It's as if python is broken.

Comment: Did you want to pop the next element just after the  `cow1.index(current)` ? for that you are using this one `cow1.pop(cow1.index(current)+1)` ?

Comment: I want to pop the element I just used, which is in this case the first element of the list, and the next one too.

Comment: so by `cow1.pop(cow1.index(current)+1)` you are meaning to pop the element next the `cow1.index(current)`   right ?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Please avoid *"Thank you"* in the question, because it doesn't help anyone to answer your question. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) on Meta StackExchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# ADDING TOTAL LITERS FOR EACH COW #
cow2 = list(cow1)
cow3 = list(cows)
cowval = []
cow_val1 = []
for cow in cows:
    cow2 = list(cow1)
    i = 0
    total1 = 0
    while cow3[0] in cow2:
        if cow3[0] == cow2[0]:
            i += 1
            cowval.append(cow2[i])
            cow2.pop(0)
            cow2.pop(0)
            i = 0
        elif cow3[0] != cow2[0]:
            cow2.pop(0)
            cow2.pop(0)
            i = 0
    cow3.pop(0)
    cow_val1.append(sum(cowval))
    cowval.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

So just try by changing like this :

```
cow1.pop(cow1.index(current)+1)
cow1.pop(cow1.index(current))
```

Expl :

In your code when you remove the first element the array's indexes will change. Then when you tries to remove the next element the index are diffrent. So first remove the next element and try to remove current elemnet

Ed :

```
for x in range(h):
  current = cow3[0]
  while current in cow3:
      cow_val.append(cow1[cow1.index(current)])
      # Changes
      cow1.pop(cow1.index(current)+1)
      cow1.pop(cow1.index(current))
      # Change here also
      cow3.pop(0)
  cow_val1.append(sum(cow_val))
```

UP :

```
c = [333, 3.0, 334, 7.0, 333, 11.0, 334, 15.0, 333, 10.0, 334, 5.0, 333, 9.0,
 334, 13.0, 333, 17.0, 334, 3.0, 333, 7.0, 334, 11.0, 333, 15.0, 334, 10.0] # I think this one you are finally getting

cows = [333, 334] # your list of cows
d = {}
for i in cows:
    d[i] = [] 

for i in range(len(c)):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        d[c[i - 1]].append(c[i])

print(d)
```

> o/p : {333: [3.0, 11.0, 10.0, 9.0, 17.0, 7.0, 15.0], 334: [7.0, 15.0, 5.0, 13.0, 3.0, 11.0, 10.0]}

```
print(sum(d[333])) # total milk of cow 333
```

> o/p : 72.0

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Datboi/Documents/test.py", line 96, in <module>
    cow_val.append(cow1[cow1.index(current)])
ValueError: 333 is not in list

Comment: are you sure you are only changed the line 97 and 98 ? Remaining all lines are same only.

Comment: I think after pop those two elemnts you want to pop the current element from cow3 also right ? So that `cow3.pop( 0 )` has to come inside the while loop . Other ways loop condition will never be false

Comment: What do you mean i dont understand

Comment: Just put that `cow3.pop(0)` inside that while loop.

Comment: I dont think thats what i want really

Comment: What i want to Do is for example; 333(this is the id), 10(cow liters), 334, 12, 333, 15, 334, 11, so on. What i want to do is to take all the numbers infront of each number for 333 and 334 into a seperate list and add them all up at once. 10+15 for cow 333, and 12+ 11 cow 334. So cow_val1 = [25,23]

Comment: just mention your input and desired output

Comment: First look at this photo, https://imgur.com/a/w6ya1 . These are the outcomes if you type or enter cow1 when the code is finished running. [333, 3.0, 334, 7.0, 333, 11.0, 334, 15.0, 333, 10.0, 334, 5.0, 333, 9.0, 334, 13.0, 333, 17.0, 334, 3.0, 333, 7.0, 334, 11.0, 333, 15.0, 334, 10.0]

Comment: I added a new piece of code in UP: answer. just check that one also

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken:

```
cow2 = list(cow1)
cow3 = list(cows)
cow_val = []
cow_val1 = []
print(cows, cow3)
for x in range(h):
    current = cow3[0]
    while current in cow3:
       cow_val.append(cow1[cow1.index(current)])
       cow1.pop(cow1.index(current))
       cow1.pop(cow1.index(current)+1)
    cow_val1.append(sum(cow_val))
    cow3.pop(0)
```

why are you popping twice here? You may want to look at your code more carefully if this is unintended.

You may want to consider re-organizing the information:

```
     {"cow_idhere":{"sunday":{"AM":0, "PM":0},     \
                    "monday":{"AM":0, "PM":0},     \
                    "tuesday":{"AM":0, "PM":0},    \
                    "wednesday":{"AM":0, "PM":0},  \
                    "thursday":{"AM":0, "PM":0},   \
                    "friday":{"AM":0, "PM":0},     \
                    "saturday":{"AM":0, "PM":0}},
      "nextcow_id": ... }
```

with functions to access to get the information. (your sections)
I don't see the need constantly pop and append with so many cows. I mean variables. 
 Example

```
def get_MilkForDay(cow_data = None, day=""):
def get_MilkForWeek(cow_data = None):
```

Also the last section (above) doesn't have a description saying what it is for. What exactly is it suppose to do?

Comment: What i want to Do is for example; 333(this is the id), 10(cow liters), 334, 12, 333, 15, 334, 11, so on. What i want to do is to take all the numbers infront of each number for 333 and 334 into a seperate list and add them all up at once. 10+15 for cow 333, and 12+ 11 cow 334. So cow_val1 = [25,23]

Comment: you can still do that. I thought you would want to keep different cows separate.

Comment: I came up with a code but it doesnt seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

```
   cow1.pop(cow1.index(current))
   cow1.pop(cow1.index(current)+1)
```

this is your error. You are doing way too many pops for what you are trying to do. stop popping the cows! tip them!

**First line**: what you are doing is looking for the index for value "333". Let's say the list has ["333","1"]. Pop the first element, now the list is ["1"]. 
**Second line**: Look for "333" - Error, the list is ["1"]

I STRONGLY recommend that you *access the information and calculate* rather than constantly changing your information. Use some functions so your base information stays the same (in some cases it won't. 
Link information together instead of having them separate and always recombining information. EG days and daya

```
days = ["monday", ... "sunday"]
#access days by days[<number>] 
     #days[0] = "monday"
     #days[1] = "tuesday" ... #days[6]="sunday"
```

You can also .append() to this!

```
milk_Evening = input("milk evening")
milk_Day = input("milk day")

days[0].append(milk_Evening)     #           day[0] [  0   , 1, 2]
days[0].append(milk_Day)         #now it looks like [monday, 1, 3]
#or
#days[0].append([milk_Evening, milk_Day])
```

How much milking on monday?
    for day_data in days:
        if day_data[0] == "monday":
            total_milk = day_data[1] + day_data[2]

Notice there was NO POPPING. Collect information. Then access information. There was not data manipulation. The information was kept the same from when it was inputted.